# Multiple templating values in FROM clause

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have influxdb and grafana set up. Templating works fine.
What I'm now trying to achieve is to have a FROM clause built from multiple templated values.

I have the following measurements defined in influxdb:

> Game1_Draw, Game1_Home, Game1_Away
>
> Game2_Draw, Game2_Home, Game2_Away
>
> .... ... ...
>
> GameN_Draw, GameN_Home, GameN_Away

I want the user to select the game name  (Game1, Game2...), and then have three graphs (not queries) with measurements (GameSelected)_Home, (GameSelected)_Away, (GameSelected)_Draw

Getting the game names from templating was easy.

What I need is to generate a query whose FROM clause will depend the game selected and a constant. Something like:

```
SELECT mean("myvalue") FROM /^$game_Home/ WHERE ....
SELECT mean("myvalue") FROM /^$game_Draw/ WHERE ....
SELECT mean("myvalue") FROM /^$game_Away/ WHERE ....
```

I cannot make this work. I cannot find anything in the documentation related to aggregate FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding information in measurement names is generally an anti-pattern in InfluxDB. The information in the separate measurement suffixes, e.g. `_Home`, `_Draw`, `_Away`, would be much more useful if it was recorded in a tag.

```
game,odds_type=home myvalue=0.5 1469923200000000000
game,odds_type=draw myvalue=0.6 1469923200000000000
game,odds_type=away myvalue=0.2 1469923200000000000
```

Then displaying these series on the same graph in Grafana would only require a group by on the `odds_type` tag.